# Binding to event property 'onlyCurrentMonth' is disallowed for security reasons After enable enableIvy:true

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular7

In my project I have used `Angular-7` after enable `ivy` in tsconfig.json showing error

[image]

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
     "compileOnSave": false,
     "compilerOptions": {
          "baseUrl": "./",
          "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "declaration": false,
          "moduleResolution": "node",
          "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
          "experimentalDecorators": true,
          "target": "es5",
          "typeRoots": [
               "node_modules/@types"
          ],
          "lib": [
               "es2017",
               "dom"
          ]
     },
     "angularCompilerOptions": {
          "enableIvy": true
     }
}
```

In my project i have used `BsDatepickerModule` Module.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Could you add some html code where this error occurs

Comment: @ssuperczynski : No i did't add the html code

Answer (score 18):

Remove the prefix "on" in "onlyCurrentMonth" and it will work.

Comment: This is technically correct. This is an issue though mostly due to Angular trying to suppress the properties starting with on*.  I am monitoring this issue on github as well.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Do you have that githubl issue for me?

Comment: This is an old question.  While you can find something similar to this by looking up the error, you can find things like mine.  The issue with Angular is that html sort of treats on as a part of onClick, onHover etc.  So if you have a prop you want to define in html, it will cause issues in the property assignment aspect of bracket assignment.  Here is jus one of the issues, which have that error. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/191

Comment: This is still the answer that worked for me.